# Identifying power connector on a Technics CD player

Tags: identification, connector

I've got a Technics CD player, model SL-XP7 and, since I don't have the original power supply, I wanted to get a connector for it, but I'm not able to find the right one.

This is the back of the device:

[image]

I took some measurements (millimetres) of the port itself:

[image]

Any ideas on what kind of connector this could be? I can fit a 3-pin JST connector if I trim the plastic a bit, but it doesn't make proper contact with the pins.

Comment: This may be the best connector identification question I've ever seen.

Comment:  thanks! just trying to give the most information in the most visual way possible  for whoever is able to help :D

Answer (score 1):

That connector is custom-made for that product.

You can buy a replacement power supply: https://www.ebay.com/itm/363852773632

Comment: Thanks! I saw those power supplies they sell, and also the original one (which is quite expensive...) That is why I wanted to get a connector, so I could connect my bench power supply and use the player.

I'm sure there must be a connector that fit that port (even if it is not 100% perfect). A JST 3 pin connector is the perfect size, but it would need a different type of "mechanism to clamp the pins".

Comment: Ya figures the question with the most completely-specified connector dimensions would be for a custom one. You *might* be able to get a Pico-Lock or something in there but it wouldn't be secure and would cost more than buying the replacement power supply.  If that eBay listing is truly the OEM power supply it looks like a bit of a hack in any case.

Comment: The thing is... if you zoom in on those ones they sell on eBay, you see how the cable is kind of hand-made with some heat-shrink tubbing etc... it may be that they are making their own connectors but I don't think so  they are maybe using one that fits well enough?

Comment: @JVLobo Maybe prying it open, desolder the connector and replace it with something more standard would be an option? Molex have lots of similar connectors that may fit physically.

Comment: I saw a really clever article once that went through the process of DIY overmolding a custom connector using some RTV compound - of course I could not find it anymore but the idea might serve as an inspiration anyway.